# Походження слова "кафи"

Tags: етимологія

В ювелірному магазині представнені різновид сережок - [кафи](https://www.zolotoyvek.ua/ua/sergi/sergi-kaffy.html) (мал.).

Сережки, які можна обягати навіть без проколювання вух (точного визначення не знайшла). Цікавить яке походження має слово *"кафи"*?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Від Анґліјської [*cuff*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuff), шчо наразі переважно означає «рукавчиком сорочки» — *[манжет](http://sum.in.ua/s/manzhet)·[а](http://sum.in.ua/s/manzheta)*. Також подекуди можна побачити поМовсовськи спотворене [*кафф*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84), котра зберігає подвоєня прихолосних.

> <sup>[**cuff**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cuff) "bottom of a sleeve," mid-14c., cuffe "hand covering, mitten, glove," perhaps from Medieval Latin cuffia, cuphia "head covering," which is of uncertain origin, perhaps ultimately from Greek.</sup>
>
> <sup>Sense of "band around the sleeve" is first attested 1520s; sense of "turned-up hem of trousers" is by 1896. Meaning "a fetter for the wrist" is from 1660s. Adverbial phrase off the cuff "extemporaneously" is attested by 1938, American English colloquial, suggesting an actor or speaker reading from notes jotted on his shirt sleeves rather than reciting learned lines. Cuff-links (also cufflinks) is from 1887.</sup>

Шчодо словопохоџеня, то там означало покритя руки, мо’ навіть рукавицї, як прикраса чи сучасна ознака зјавилася з 17 віку. А саме давніше похоџенє не дуже відомо, є думка, що від Середнӧлатинької, де значило покритя голови. А першоџерело не відоме — є лиш гадки про Елаѕьку.